# Why does repr(a) truncate a.__repr__(), but f'{a!r}' doesn't?

Tags: python, repr, f-string

I have a number of custom python objects with custom `__repr__()` functions. Each of them uses f-strings to generate the output `str`. One of the objects' contains other custom objects, so there are `repr`s inside of its `repr`.

The parent object's `repr` is declared like this:

```py
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Lexc(multichars={repr(self.multichar_symbols)}, {len(self.lexicons)} lexicons)'
```

The `__repr__` for the class of `self.multichar_symbols` is like this:

```py
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'MulticharSymbols({len(self.symbols)} symbols, {len(self.lines)} lines)'
```

Here is the question. I would have expected the following code to produce the exact same output three times in a row, but as you can see, the f-string and `__repr__()` produces a full `repr` and the `repr()` produces a truncated `repr` (with `...` inserted).

```py
print(f'{lexc!r}')
print(lexc.__repr__())
print(repr(lexc))
print()
print(f'{lexc.multichar_symbols!r}')
print(lexc.multichar_symbols.__repr__())
print(repr(lexc.multichar_symbols))
```

```py
Lexc(multichars=MulticharSymbols(187 symbols, 190 lines), 2611 lexicons)
Lexc(multichars=MulticharSymbols(187 symbols, 190 lines), 2611 lexicons)
Lexc(multicha...2611 lexicons)

MulticharSymbols(187 symbols, 190 lines)
MulticharSymbols(187 symbols, 190 lines)
MulticharSymb...ls, 190 lines)
```

Unfortunately, I have been unable to reduce this behavior to a minimal working example, so part of the question is what mechanism could be causing this. The [documentation for f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) states that...

> If a conversion is specified, the result of evaluating the expression is converted before formatting. Conversion `'!s'` calls `str()` on the result, `'!r'` calls `repr()`, and `'!a'` calls `ascii()`.

If that were the case, then the results should be identical. The documentation for `repr()` and `__repr__()` do not seem to have any relevant information.

Why does `repr()` yield truncated results to 30 characters, and how can I recreate this behavior with a minimal example?

Comment: It sounds like you may have put a `__repr__` entry in the instance dict, or you may have replaced `repr` itself.

Comment: The output you've shown is most consistent with something weird shadowing `repr`.

Comment: What does `print(repr.__module__)` give you?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica you're exactly right. I copied some code and didn't notice that it had `from reprlib import repr` in it. So @IainShelvington's comment gives the output `reprlib`. Thanks, friends!

Comment: I should have googled `repr 30 characters`. Takes you straight to the `reprlib` docs.